# How to move a class of objects in pygame?

Tags: python, class, pygame, move

I have a class of `pygame.draw.rect`s like the one below:

```
pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, BROWN, (x+25,  y+35,   5,   5))
```

These are all under the class `Archer()`, in the function `draw(x, y)`. However, I would like to move all of these objects as one. How would I move all of the objects within this class without moving each individual one? My code is here: http://pastebin.com/APkgTnTk

Comment: and what is wrong with your current code?

Comment: I think the problem is that your move code is just setting the position to the same point (10,10) each time in your loop. In move, did you perhaps mean `self.x += newx`?

Comment: But then that just draws a whole new `Archer`, with he previous one still there. Can I remove the previous one?

Comment: @aj8uppal Well first of all, you are creating a new `Archer()` instance every loop, so you should move the `myarcher = Archer()` to before your `for` loop. Secondly, you should call `windowSurface.fill(BLACK)` every frame before you draw if you want to clear the screen before drawing again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include these objects in a RenderUpdates group. This lets you draw the items on the screen as one, and call functions on them as one. For example, you could do:

```
window_surfaces = pygame.sprite.RenderUpdates()
```

then include inside the **init** function of the class you want to call in a group:

```
window_surfaces.add(self)
```

then, when you want to call a function on all of them, you can call

```
window_surfaces.draw()
```

You might consider containing the individual arguments for each class inside "self" beforehand.

Also, if you just want to draw a group of sprites at their current location, you could just call:

```
pygame.display.update(window_surfaces.draw(screen))
```

Be aware, however, that this draw function is not the one you defined, but one built in to the render updates object. If you use render updates you probably don't want to overwrite this function.

Also, it seems that you may, in fact, not be using sprites. If this is the case (and you may want to seriously consider using them, they come with many useful features that you have to build from scratch built into them) than you will want to have the classes append themselves to a list in the **init** function, then use a for loop to call the function like so:

```
for itemtodraw in mygroup:
    itemtodraw.draw()
```